# How to add or subtract the elements of a list to a variable depending on their value?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

How to add or subtract the elements of a list to a variable depending on their value in Python? Is there any way to do it?

Note: The value of the elements in the list and the length of the list does not remain constant.

For example:

```
thislist = [1,4,6,10,18]
x = 5
```

If the value of any element in the list is >= 5, I would like to subtract `x` from the element. Otherwise (if the value of any element is lower than 5), I would subtract the element from x.

Comment: `[abs(x-5) for x in [1, 4, 6, 10, 18]]`

Comment: If àny answer helps close the question by accepting it as an solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` also:

```
list(map(lambda el: abs(el - x), thislist))
```

---

```
[4, 1, 1, 5, 13]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate through `thislist`. The result you want is the absolute value of `m - x`, where `m` is the element of `thislist`

```
thislist = [1, 4, 6, 10, 18]
x = 5
[abs(m - x) for m in thislist]
```